# How to add uiviewcontroller's view as content view to uitableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to add a uiviewcontroller's view which has a button and few labels as a content view of a uitableviewcell.

Though i am able to add but the button action causes a crash.

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initwithnibname:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
[cell.contentview addsubview:controller.view];
[controller release]; // if i comment out this part the button action is received by my view controller.
```

However there are memory leaks when its removed from view. The dealloc of myviewcontroller is not called.

What is the correct way to do this?

1. Add a view to a uitableview cell
   which has a button and is handled by
   the viewcontroller
2. How to assure memory is released
   when the view goes out of scope?

TIA,
Praveen

Comment: Post some crash log. Check your Console for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you are releasing the controller and just using the subview which is retained by its superview. The action pattern needs a target which I assume is the released controller. And why should you release your viewController if you only need the view of it? Retain it and keep a reference through a property to it.

My way of adding subviews to a tableview cell would be in a subclass of UITableViewCell. Let's assume you are having a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, say `ButtonTableViewCell`. The init of the of cell creates and adds a UIButton to your cell and puts it nicely in its contentView. Decalre a property which references to the button. Like `UIButton *myButton`. What should be done in the cellForRowAtIndexPath is something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ButtonTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyButtonCell"];           
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ButtonTableViewCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyButtonCell"];
    }
    [cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onDoSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Do more cell configuration...
    return cell;
}
```

I've made up the initializer `initWithReuseIdentifier` which can be easily implemented.

You assure release of memory with the [viewDidUnload](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW36) method of the [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the dealloc method.

Comment: The button action on the uiview is called only if i dont release the controller. How can the controller get the button click event if i have to have efficient memory management?

Comment: Who says that releasing the controller is efficient memory usage if you need it? The current controller will receive a memory warning if you run out of memory. This will trigger unloading of views.

Comment: I am not releasing the controller. But i want the controller's (IBAction) to be called and also when the tableview is deallocated the  controller's dealloc to be called. Its not being called in my case.

Comment: Well, if you retain the instance of the controller the IBAction should be called. I think the problem is still the configuration of the cell. I'll put some more info my answer.

Answer (score 1):

"button action causes a crash" - What is the crash when you tap the button?

Also, you only appear to be using the view of MyViewController (since you add the view to the cell and then release the controller)- what is this controller supposed to do other than contain a view?  Why not just use a view?

Also, (wild guess here) the usual constructor of a button does not have new/alloc/copy, and therefore does not warrant a release.  I've seen a lot of code crash from inappropriately releasing UIButton's.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a view of a controller as a `subview` to any other view does not retain the controller.
The controller is released immediately after the release call and any button actions will be sent to deallocated instance.

We can avoid this by maintaining a strong reference to the controller

```
@Property(nonatomic,strong)MyViewController *controller;
```

or by adding a view controller as the **ChildViewController**

```
[self addChildViewController:controller];
```

Comment: how to do this in swift ?

Comment: ok i was doing `let someVC  = SomeViewController.init(..)`  inside view did load of cell , by putting `someVC` outside `viewdidload` as `var someVC:SomeViewController?` and then init it in view did load maintains reference .

May help someone