# How to add a UIViewController's view as a subview to a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a reusable `UIViewController` subclass (an audio/video player, let's call it `MediaController`). It works ok when I add it to some other view controller as a child view controller, however my requirement is to also add it in a `UITableViewCell` subclass. Since  `-addChildViewController:` is a method of `UIViewController`, I'm adding my view to the cell like that:

```
self.mediaController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
[self.containerView addSubview:self.mediaController.view];
```

(`containerView` is just a placeholder view in the cell's view hierarchy).

However, this causes problems, first because MediaController is having some logic in `-viewWillAppear` and `-viewWillDisappear` (that of course never get called) and second because it seems that autolayout does not work properly when MediaController's view is added to the cell.

Do you think I have some other option (maybe use the UITableViewController that owns the cell as a container?) or I will not be able to use this MediaController at all?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596247/how-to-add-uiviewcontrollers-view-as-content-view-to-uitableviewcell) is the most relevant when I search, but it still doesn't solve my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: May it would be ok to call manually MediaController lifecycle methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [other answer from aahrens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23785325/289501) did not work for me since I have a complicated table view and I was not using storyboards from the beginning.

What I ended up doing was to pass a weak reference of the `UIViewController` to the cell, so that I can make the "normal" call to `-addChildViewController:`. Ugly, but works fine.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I might try if it's possible is to have a `UITableViewController` that has static cells.

If you're using a `UIStoryboard` drag and drop a `UITableViewController` and change the `content` to `Static Cells` then in the cell you want to have your `MediaController` drop a `Container View` into that cell. Then drag and drop from that `Container View` to your `MediaController` and setup an embed segue.

The appropriate viewLifecycle methods should be called when displaying.

Here is the `UIStoryboard` setup
[image]

Comment: I might not have understood correctly, but are you sure you can drag n drop from a view to a view controller..? What is an "embed segue"? Can you provide a screenshot of this setup?

Comment: Updated with a screenshot for the setup

Comment: Thanks for your time. I upvoted your answer but in the end had to use a different approach since it was not possible to use storyboards.